# How to count every 5 consecutive absences in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I wonder how to count 5 consecutive absences of pupils/students in a month. Any help?

Note: I would like to attach my rough excel file but it seems no option for that.

Comment: Share a sample of the data and your formulas using text. We do not support file uploads because people should be able to write their problem in their question. You can edit your question to provide data and samples you have tried: https://superuser.com/posts/1221330/edit

Comment: Bear in mind that you should show us what you have tried and tell us how it is or is not working.

Comment: You can post a sample file on any free file sharing service (OneDrive, Dropbox, Box, etc) and share a link here. Or show a screenshot of your file with the expected result marked in manually. Edit your post to provide that, then explain the logic that leads to the result. Don't put that into a comment. Edit your post! Then you can add a comment to alert people who are following your question.

Comment: countif or countifs should do what you want - use the month as criteria.